# Are theoretical questions about legal systems on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are **theoretical** questions about legal process on-topic for the main site?

For example, I am curious about the inevitable complexity that follows the precedent system in the common law.  If I were to ask about it, would it be on topic?  If it's not, what if I asked a question how such complexity is handled by various legal systems which utilize the common law?  Would that be too theoretical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tags on the main site that would seem appropriate for those types of questions.  You might peruse the questions under those to get a sense of what sorts of theoretical questions have gotten good ratings and good answers in the past:

- [legal-theory](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-theory)
- [legal-concepts](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-concepts)
- [common-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-law)

However, as on all Stack Exchanges, questions that are too broad and questions that are too vague to admit good answers might be closed.